# Perl - geturls with WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, mechanize, www-mechanize

I am trying to submit a form on `http://bioinfo.noble.org/TrSSP/` and want to extract the result.

My query data looks like this

```
>ATCG00270
MTIALGKFTKDEKDLFDIMDDWLRRDRFVFVGWSGLLLFPCAYFALGGWFTGTTFVTSWYTHGLASSYLEGCNFLTAA    VSTPANSLAHSLLLLWGPEAQGDFTRWCQLGGLWAFVALHGAFALIGFMLRQFELARSVQLRPYNAIAFSGPIAVFVSVFLIYPLGQSGWFFAPSFGVAAIFRFILFFQGFHNWTLNPFHMMGVAGVLGAALLCAIHGATVENTLFEDGDGANTFRAFNPTQAEETYSMVTANRFWSQIFGVAFSNKRWLHFFMLFVPVTGLWMSALGVVGLALNLRAYDFVSQEIRAAEDPEFETFYTKNILLNEGIRAWMAAQDQPHENLIFPEEVLPRGNAL
```

My script looks like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

my $sequence = $ARGV[0];

$mech->get( 'http://bioinfo.noble.org/TrSSP' );
$mech->submit_form( fields => { 'query_file' => $sequence, }, );

print $mech->content;

#sleep (10);

open( OUT, ">out.txt" );

my @a = $mech->find_all_links();

print OUT "\n", $a[$_]->url for ( 0 .. $#a );
```

`print $mech->content` gives a result like this

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>

    <head>
      <title>The job is running, please wait...</title>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4;url=/TrSSP/?sessionid=1492435151653763">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="interface/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<table width="90%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  class="table1">

  <tr align="center">
    <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr align="left" height="30" valign="middle">
    <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgColor="#CCCCFF">&nbsp;Your sequences have been submitted to backend pipeline, please wait for result:</td>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr align="left">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>

<br><br><font color="#0000FF"><strong>
&nbsp;</strong></font>
<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><br><br><BR><br><br><hr>
If you don't want to wait online, please copy and keep the following link to retrieve your result later:<br>

<strong>http://bioinfo.noble.org/TrSSP/?sessionid=1492435151653763</strong>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
function doit()
{
    window.location.href="/TrSSP/?sessionid=1492435151653763";
}
setTimeout("doit()",9000);
</script>

    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
    </html>
```

I want to extract this link

```
http://bioinfo.noble.org/TrSSP/?sessionid=1492435151653763
```

and download the result when the job is completed. But `find_all_links()` is recognizing `/TrSSP/?sessionid=1492434554474809` as a link.

Comment: *"download the result when the job is completed"* Are you hoping to poll that address until it provides a finished result?

Comment: Actually my final goal is to extract the result that appear on that address. But I am not sure how long it will take. Therefore I am think to extract the address (http://bioinfo.noble.org/TrSSP/?sessionid=1492435151653763) and then pull the result after sometime later. But again I am not sure that this will be the best way to do this job. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know how long this is backend process there is going to take. If it's minutes, you could have your program wait. Even if it's hours, waiting is reasonable.

In a browser, the page is going to refresh on its own. There are two auto-refresh mechanisms implemented in the response you are showing.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
function doit()
{
    window.location.href="/TrSSP/?sessionid=1492435151653763";
}
setTimeout("doit()",9000);
</script>
```

The javascript `setTimeout` takes an argument in milliseconds, so this will be done after 9 seconds.

There is also a meta tag that tells the browser to auto-refresh:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4;url=/TrSSP/?sessionid=1492435151653763">
```

Here, the `4` in the `content` means 4 seconds. So this would be done earlier.

Of course we also don't know how long they keep the session around. It might be a safe approach to reload that page every ten seconds (or more often, if you want).

You can do that by building a simple `while` loop and checking if the refresh is still in the response.

```
# do the initial submit here

... 

# assign this by grabbing it from the page
$mech->content =~ m{<strong>(\Qhttp://bioinfo.noble.org/TrSSP/?sessionid=\E\d+)</strong>};
my $url = $1; # in this case, regex on HTML is fine

print "Waiting for $url\n";
while (1) {
     $mech->get($url);
     last unless $mech->content =~ m/refresh/;
     sleep 10; # or whatever number of seconds
}

# process the final response ...
```

We first submit the data. We then extract the URL that you're supposed to call until they are done processing. Since this is a pretty straight-forward document, we can safely use a pattern match. The URL is always the same, and it's clearly marked with the `<strong>` tag. In [general it's not a good idea to use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1331451), but we're not really parsing, we are just [screenscraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping#Screen_scraping) a single value. The `\Q` and `\E` are the same as [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) and make sure that we don't have to escape the `.` and `?`, which is then easier to read than having a buch of backslashes `\` in the pattern.

The script will [`sleep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html) for ten seconds after every attempt before trying again. Once it matches, it breaks out of the endless loop, so you can put the processing of the actual response that has the data you wanted behind that loop.

It might make sense to add some output into the loop so you can see that it's still running.

Note that this needs to really keep running until it's done. Don't stop the process.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was doing the whole process in multiple steps by multiple scripts. After submission, I was extracting the right url. After that I was downloading the web page and finally html table parsing. You make my life easier :). Now I think I can directly parse my result like this  my $text = `read_file($mech);
my $te = new HTML::TableExtract();
 $te->parse($text);

foreach my $ts ($te ->table_states) {
        foreach my $row ($ts->rows) 
{
       print "   ", join(',', @$row), "\n";
   
 }

}
`

Comment: @pali glad to hear that it works. While you're at it, stop using indirect object notation. Don't do `new HTML::TableExtract`. Do `HTML::TableExtract->new` instead. The indirect object notation can lead to ambiguous syntax where perl gets confused, among other things. :)

Comment: Thanks for your insights.